# Phone Icon to only appear on mobile view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

On my website I have a phone icon so on mobile view they can click on the phone icon and ring a certain business, I can't figure out how to have it only appear on mobile view.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #tel {display:none;}
  @media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #tel {display:block;}
  }
</style>

<div class="tel">
<a href="tel:555-555-5555"><img src="images/phone.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#tel
```

refers to an id, you have to use

```
.tel
```

in the css

Answer (score 0):

```
/* mobile call links  */
a[href^="tel:"] {

color: inherit; 
text-decoration: none; 
cursor: default;
display:none;

}
```

the above will hide your cursor for non-mobile browsers so it wont work as link.
you can do a